# Forward button and/or history

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I often accidentally press Back button which returns me to home screen (from widget) or to main app screen, and because both are auto-updated I see no way to restore page on which I was.

Can we please have a Forward button, or "history"?

Edit: as @Andrew mentioned this can be against Android app guidelines. Yet I think it's more important to provide better user experience. If the browser provides better ux by ability to navigate through history why not integrate this feature in an app which basically *is* a browser?

Comment: Even though I can agree with your reasoning, I never see Forward or History button on any other apps (except browser, of course), so I'm afraid this will conflict with Android's standard design guideline. What I'd consider is instead, a confirmation dialog when you press Back button, and certainly with toggleable setting, since not everyone want to have this feature. I still feel my suggestion is not the best idea though, so let's wait for official response.

Comment: The history is a definite must! Especially when you have the app to open stackexchange sites automatically